# Android Virtual Device emulator is working awfully slow

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I've got 4GB of RAM memory @800mhz, Phenom 9750 x4 @2.4GHz, yet the emulator is working really slow. I'm currently learning the basics of Android development, so I wonder, what should I do to maximize the performance of the emulator? Which device do I pick and what should be the settings? I do realize my PC is outdated and slow, but surely it can do better?

Comment: The emulator is always slow. It's best to test on devices if possible.

Comment: Note that the emulator only uses one core, so unless the Phenom has AMD's equivalent of Intel's "Turbo Boost", the additional cores will not help the emulator much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't emulating another architecture in your settings. Choose Intel instead of any others and try again. I think you have to create a new device but I'm not certain.